# How to open a .jpg image using QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlistwidget

I am having some .jpg images in a folder which need to be displayed in QtListWidget. I am able to display the list of items in a particular folder in QtListWidget, but unable to open the item when i click it. I learned in tutorial one should use "connect" for doing it, i tried it but error is happening.
My code in .cpp file is as follows. Any help is most welcomed...

```
QDir myPath("/home/mit/Desktop/Ui_dev_mits_cars/visual_image");
myPath.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
myList = myPath.entryList();
ui->listWidget1->addItems(myList);
```

Comment: Where is your connect trial?

Comment: My connect trail is     connect(MyList,SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *)),this,SLOT(test(QListWidgetItem *)));   This connect when executed an error   "no matching function for call to'calibration::connect(QStringList&....)" is happening

Comment: The first argument should be `ui->listWidget1` rather than MyList which is a QStringList, not even a pointer in fact. Does it work if you change that?

Comment: Thanks Laszlo now error is not coming..but the images are not getting displayed in application output tab of QT some error like   Object::connect No such signal QListWidget::doubleClicked(QListWidgetIten *)    Object::connect:(sender name: 'listWidget1')    Object::connect(receiver name: 'calibration')  is coming

Comment: Cause you should use the model index as the parameter! Also, you had a typo just in case.

Comment: Sorry dats a typing mistake..Its QListWidgetItem itself..

Comment: Sam, why should we care about the questions anymore if you do not care about the answers given?

Answer (score 1):

Right, so the issue is at least two-folded with your code:

```
connect(MyList,SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *)),this,SLOT(test(QListWidgetItem *)));
```

First of all, you are trying to use a `QStringList` value based object rather than pointer. Also, you should use the pointer pointing to the `QListWidget` instance.

Secondly, you are using the signal wrong. It is parameter is a `QModelIndex` as opposed to a `QListWidgetItem`. See the documentation for details:

> [void QAbstractItemView::doubleClicked(const QModelIndex & index) [signal]](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked)
>
> This signal is emitted when a mouse button is double-clicked. The item the mouse was double-clicked on is specified by index. The signal is only emitted when the index is valid.

So, grab the model index and in your slot, get the data out of that model index either by using the internal pointer, or preferrably the `data()` method.